# Parsing file and creating a key value pair that fits a certain criteria

Tags: javascript, parsing, object

I have got three different sets of data - Where Who and When. The structure of the results file will never change only the results inside (the values such as the numbers etc) but the layout will always stay the same.

I am trying to parse the file so when I upload the file and run it through the `fileReader` it manipulates the set records and uses the one given from the document.

Currently, this is the view of the page:

[image]

This is what populates it and gives it the appropriate color.

```
function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Occurrences'],
        ['Germany', 55],
        ['United States', 328],
        ['Brazil', 119],
        ['United Kingdom', 39],
        ['Italy', 39],
        ['Canada', 40],
        ['greenland', 80]
      ]);

      var options = {};

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Above is the function, and below I will provide the results data.

```
journalism.When

2000 --> 219

2003 --> 194

1998 --> 190

2001 --> 173

2004 --> 155

2002 --> 155

1995 --> 144

2008 --> 127

1997 --> 123

1994 --> 117



journalism.Who

Atmos --> 85

J. Geophys --> 77

OECD --> 70

Grossman --> 56

EPA --> 54

PBL --> 49

Krueger --> 45

Stern --> 43

Selden --> 42

Taylor --> 41



journalism.Where

US --> 129

São Paulo --> 115

Brazil --> 104

U.S. --> 76

Germany --> 55

USA --> 45

America --> 42

Italy --> 39

UK --> 39

LA --> 36
```

So for this parsing, I would need it to ignore the first two sections and only read the bottom section which is `journalism. Where`.

What would be the best way to work around this, I have never really worked much with parsing data. This is all done with VanillaJS. Any feedback or help would be highly appreciated. I have a few ideas on how I could work this out but I wanted to ask on here to see if anyone has a really good technique.

Comment: Is the result data you posted off _literal_? I mean: Are there lines like "journalism.who" etc, as embedded headers within the text?

Comment: So it's a text file, there are no headers I would say? So the program prints it out line by line onto the text file and there are three different sections the first is the when, followed by who and then where, as the post above shows. Hopefully, this answers the question? @LittleSanti

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your grammar is extremely simple, it doesn't require any advanced parsing techniques, you can easily sort this out with `split` and `for` loops.

You basically can split the source string by `\n\n\n\n` to split each key. Then, for each block, you can split by another `\n\n` which would give you lines of data where you can have the first item as the key name [`journalist.who`, ...] and iterate over the other lines splitting them by `-->` and take key and value for the first and second item resultant from the split.

The final result would be something like the function bellow:

```
function parseData(src) {
  var blocks = src.split('\n\n\n\n');
  var keys = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    var block = blocks[i].split('\n\n');
    var label = block[0];
    var key = keys[label] = {};

    for (var j = 1; j < block.length; j++) {
        var data = block[j].split(' --> ');
            key[data[0]] = data[1];
    }
  }

  return keys;
}
```

> **Warning:** if you are using windows like line ending style [`\r\n`], you have to split by `\r\n` instead of `\n` or you can remove all the `\r` before parsing like this:
>
> ```
> var src = `...`;
>
> src = src.replace(/\r/g, '');
>
> var data = parseData(src);
> ```

Bellow there is a working snippet of the solution I described.

```js
var src = `journalism.When

2000 --> 219

2003 --> 194

1998 --> 190

2001 --> 173

2004 --> 155

2002 --> 155

1995 --> 144

2008 --> 127

1997 --> 123

1994 --> 117



journalism.Who

Atmos --> 85

J. Geophys --> 77

OECD --> 70

Grossman --> 56

EPA --> 54

PBL --> 49

Krueger --> 45

Stern --> 43

Selden --> 42

Taylor --> 41



journalism.Where

US --> 129

São Paulo --> 115

Brazil --> 104

U.S. --> 76

Germany --> 55

USA --> 45

America --> 42

Italy --> 39

UK --> 39

LA --> 36`;

function parseData(src) {
  var blocks = src.split('\n\n\n\n');
  var keys = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    var block = blocks[i].split('\n\n');
    var label = block[0];
    var key = keys[label] = {};

    for (var j = 1; j < block.length; j++) {
      var data = block[j].split(' --> ');
      key[data[0]] = data[1];
    }
  }

  return keys;
}

var data = parseData(src);

document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`);
```

Comment: That looks really good and super simple, the power of parsing. Is there a way to have three different arrays one named: `When = []; Who = []; Where = [];` Not sure which way I could simplify this further.  The result is great that you have given me, just need to figure out how to dig into the last object as there are three, and replacing `var data` values with the new values. @lenilsondc Thanks for that code snippet its great!

Comment: The function returns an object containing all keys, just take the one which you'd like to use like so: `var data = parseData(src); var when = data["journalism.Where"]`; simple as that :D

Comment: Okay, thanks that sounds amazing, this is the result I have got when I implemented it into my system: Log is too long so I will have to make a gist: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/5544fbc32a23eb507f0386862e79fd88

Comment: You are using windows `\r\n` end of line ending style therefore you have to split by `\r\n` instead of `\n` or remove all the `\r` before parsing. I'll add a note on that.

Comment: Your data is using a line ending token mostly used on windows which is `\r\n` (a.k.a. `CrLf`) on unix and linux like is used only `\n` (a.k.a. `Lf`) that is what I meant.

Comment: This is my current layout now, since I'm getting the info from the fileReader: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/d3db9393e3030cb2733bbc909a51e3b4 Do you know what the issue could be? Sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179760/discussion-between-andrew-and-lenilsondc).

Comment: When using a FileReader it seems to remove spaces, that why this is not working for me, been trying to speak in the discussion but got no replies. The main issue is the Filereader. I can show the result after the file gets pulled in via the fileReader.